# How do I bypass Visual Studio 2005 SP1 failing to install on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2005 in Windows 7. When attempting to start, Windows 7 complains that Visual Studio 2005 is incompatible with Windows 7 and offers me to search online for a solution. It comes up with a link to Visual Studio 2005 SP1 for Windows Vista and Windows 7, but when I download it (VS80sp1-KB932232-X86-ENU.exe) and try to run it, it refuses to install saying that

> The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.

Comment: Why do you need to install VS2005? Without knowing this, all we can suggest is to install VS2008 instead.

Comment: Switching VS-versions is not something we can do lightly; we need to do it (as I understand it) more or less on a company-wide basis. We are, however, in the process of switching to VS2008, but I still need to be able to build with VS2005 now and then.

Comment: If this is your company machine then ask IT - unless you are IT of course!

Comment: Deciding on compiler versions is not something we dare leave to our IT-department.

Comment: There are very good reasons to continue to use VS 2005, for example, the xsd designer

Comment: Programmers should supersede IT for their own machines, especially when it comes to their area of specialty: software development. Or straddle the fine line between programmer roles and unofficial IT. Also, I agree, upgrading to a newer version is not trivial.

Comment: There you go @JesperE :-) Great question btw!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to ignore the warning and install VS 2005, then SP1 and then the [VS2005-Vista update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=90E2942D-3AD1-4873-A2EE-4ACC0AACE5B6&displaylang=en). *Three* installs.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 might not be compatible with Windows 7:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c26cc39%28VS.80%29.aspx

> **Operating System**
>
> Windows 2000 Service
>   Pack 4, Windows XP Service Pack 2,
>   Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, or
>   Windows Vista3,4
>
> For a 64-bit computer, the
>   requirements are as follows:
>
> Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 x64
>   editions
>
> Windows XP Professional x64 Edition

Comment: **NB** these compatibility lists don't always get updated. There is a specific post VS2005-SP1 patch for Vista.

Comment: VS2005 actually is compatible with Windows 7, I just misunderstood how to install the patch to SP1 for Vista.

Comment: -1, VS2005 is compatible with windows 7. but as other users have put in their answers "you need install VS2005, then VS2005 SP1, then VS2005-Vista-Update" in order to get VS 2005 to run in windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7).