# Visual Studio 2005 won't install on Windows 7

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2005, windows-7

My question relates very closely to this question:
[How do I bypass Visual Studio 2005 SP1 failing to install on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/34190/visual-studio-2005-sp1-refuses-to-install-in-windows-7)

However this question hasn't provided the answer I'm looking for.
I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2005 onto a clean Windows 7 (64 bit) box. However I keep getting the following error when the 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2005' component finishes installing ...

> Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'policy.8.0.Microsoft.VC80.OpenMP,type="win32-policy",version="8.0.50727.42",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80073712.

On my first attempt to install VS 2005 I got a warning about compatibility issues. I stopped at this point, downloaded the necessary service packs and restarted the installation from the beginning. Every since then I just get the error message above. I keep rolling back the installation and trying again ... it's but always the same error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this error message indicates the component store has been corrupted. You could take a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=947821

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It was the component store that was corrupted but in the end I had to re-install windows :-(.